# Spring lookup-method instance creation

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Spring lookup-method attribute used for method injection which helps to creates the fresh instances every time when that method is invoked. Also container dynamically creates the subclass for that class and overrides that method. But, for me only one instances created for the normal injection and method injection. I have posted the complete code what I have tried. I want to understand completely how lookup-method working and how it is different from the normal injection.

```
<bean id="processor" class="org.RequestProcessor">
        <lookup-method name="getResourceA" bean="resourceA"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="resourceA" class="org.ResourceA"/>
    <bean id="resourceB" class="org.ResourceB"/>


public abstract class RequestProcessor {
    @Autowired
    ResourceB resourceB;
    public ResourceB getResourceB(){
        return resourceB;
    }

    abstract ResourceA getResourceA();
}


public class ResourceA {
    String url ="http://localhost:8080";
    public ResourceA(){
        System.out.println("Resource A instance creation");
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}


public class ResourceB {
    String url ="http://localhost:8081";
    public ResourceB(){
        System.out.println("Resource B instance creation");
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}


public class SpringExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("org/applicationContext.xml");
        RequestProcessor processor = (RequestProcessor)applicationContext.getBean("processor");     
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
            ResourceA resource = processor.getResourceA();
            System.out.println(resource.getUrl());
        }
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
            ResourceB resource = processor.getResourceB();
            System.out.println(resource.getUrl());
        }       
    }
}
```

output for the above program is:

```
Resource B instance creation
Resource A instance creation
http://localhost:8080
http://localhost:8080
http://localhost:8080
http://localhost:8081
http://localhost:8081
http://localhost:8081
```

Comment: can you tell me ow to set lookup-method via java code, I am creating bean at runtime and want to hookup lookup-method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer for my problem. I have missed scope attribute in the two beans. I have to add scope="prototype" to two beans like:

```
<bean id="resourceA" class="org.ResourceA" scope="prototype"/>
<bean id="resourceB" class="org.ResourceB" scope="prototype"/>
```

After the change now the output is:

```
Resource B instance creation
Resource A instance creation
http://localhost:8080
Resource A instance creation
http://localhost:8080
Resource A instance creation
http://localhost:8080
http://localhost:8081
http://localhost:8081
http://localhost:8081
```